# How do I plot -log(x)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So for a presentation, i'm comparing 2 things, a linear relationship and a log relationship.

I've already created the code for the linear graph but i'm having  trouble creating the negative log graph.

Incase anyone isn't sure the shape of the graph i'm talking about, i've included the following link.

https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS693US693&sxsrf=ALeKk03_u2BeRiXO5dhM9icnpAr36NrPyA%3A1602378142971&ei=nlmCX7LmOu6E_QayxKrwBw&q=graph+of+-+ln%28x%29&oq=graph+of+-+ln%28x%29&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHOgQIIxAnUKIyWK00YIc2aABwAngAgAFniAGyAZIBAzEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiyrYfgq6vsAhVuQt8KHTKiCn4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5

I would really appreciate any insight on how the heck i make this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The question is too general - why don't you add some code

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)
y = -np.log(x)
# Plot y=x
plt.plot(x, x)
# Plot y = -log(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Keep in mind that the log of zero (or any negative number) is undefined.

Comment: This did the trick but with a small correction! The last value of linspace is for number of elements, not the step (just an FYI)

Thank you so much! it slipped my mind that Python wouldn't graph log(0). In my head, I just assumed it would plot the asymptote and move forward with the next step. Coding goof from me!

Comment: Ah yep, I always mix up the arguments for np.linspace and np.arange. Should've tried running the code first sorry!